# Corollary of Wiener process and the the appearance of $\sqrt{t}$

Tags: probability, simulations, stochastic-processes, non-equilibrium, brownian-motion

One of the properties of a Wiener process is given by (taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process),

> A corollary useful for simulation is that we can write, for $t_1 < t_2$:
> $$W_{t_2} = W_{t_1} + \sqrt{t_2 - t_1} \cdot Z$$
> where $Z$ is an independent standard normal variable.

How do we prove this identity?

Comment: This is a good question. In a real sense, this property could be seen as the definition of a Weiner process, so let me ask: what do you want to take as the definition from which we drive this property?

Comment: Can we start from proving the property W(t+s) - W(t) $\approx$ $N(0,s)$? I mean, can we prove this property first and then prove the stuff what I have mentioned above?

Comment: Again, what's your starting point? To prove something you need a starting set of information.

Comment: $\bar{dW(t)dW(t)}$=dt , this can be taken as the starting point. Now can we start from this point?